# Is the "center-of-mass energy" in particle physics related to the center-of-mass frame or not?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, mass, collision, inertial-frames

For collision of particles the invariant quantity **"center-of-mass energy"** is defined, as done [here](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-kinematics.pdf).

Since it is an invariant quantity it does not depend on the frame of reference chosen. So the name **"center-of-mass"** here is not to be related to the center-of-mass **frame**? Does this have anything to do with the center-of-mass frame or not?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The center-of-mass energy is the energy as measured in the frame where:
$$0=\sum_i \vec p_i\tag{1}$$
i.e. the sum of all 3-momenta is zero.

---

In a general inertial frame $r$ where the 4-momenta is given by $P_i^r$ we have the quantity:
$$\Lambda^2=\left(\sum_i P_i^r\right)^\mu \left(\sum_j P_j^r\right)_\mu\tag{2}$$
here all Lorentz indices are contracted (using the $\eta=(+---)$ metric) and such $\Lambda$ is Lorentz invariant.

Now let us calculate $\Lambda$ in the CofM frame (I actually prefer the term 'zero momentum frame') here we have that (due to (1)):
$$\sum_i P_i^r=\begin{pmatrix} E_{CM} \\0 \\0 \\0\end{pmatrix}$$
where $E_{cm}=\sum_i E_i$ hence subbing this into (2) we get:
$$\Lambda^2=E_{cm}^2$$
so $\Lambda=E_{cm}$ (spare a sign which we define to be $+$).

Thus to summarize:

- $\Lambda$ is Lorentz invariant.
- When calculated in the cofm frame it is equal to the total energy $E_{cm}$.
- Thus in any frame it is equal to $E_{cm}$ hence we call $\Lambda$ the center of mass energy.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Allow me a comment on "the term 'zero momentum frame'" (ZMF). We can have a ZMF that's not the CofM frame (CofMF). To be the CofMF, we need: (1) sum of the particles' 3-momenta to be **0** _AND_ (2) origin to be at the particles' center of mass. Consider two neutrons, 2 units of space apart, heading directly away from each other, each with a speed of 1. Ex. ZMF, not CofMF: **r1** =(3,-1,0), **r2** =(3,1,0), **v1** =(0,-1,0), **v2** =(0,1,0) `=>` sum(**p**)= **0**, **r_cofm** =(3,0,0) != (0,0,0). For CofMF, redefine coord. sys. such that all is the same except r1_x=r2_x=0

Comment: See archived [Wikipedia.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20230519203855/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center-of-momentum_frame) for restatements of this. "In physics, the center-of-momentum frame [is] also known as zero-momentum frame" ... "[ZMF] is unique up to velocity, but not origin." ... "A special case of the center-of-momentum frame is the center-of-mass frame: an inertial frame in which the center of mass (which is a single point) remains at the origin. In all center-of-momentum frames, the center of mass is at rest, but it is not necessarily at the origin of the coordinate system."