# (Cold?) fusion by combining protons and electrons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, hydrogen, fusion, binding-energy, cold-fusion

How does one remove electrons from hydrogen nuclei?

Using a [tokamak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak)?

In any case, do we really need millions of degrees centigrade of temperature to get an electron to fuse with a proton?

To make a long question short, if I accelerate a bunch of electrons using the LHC or equivalent and target them at liquid hydrogen (instead of plasma) is the chance of electrons hitting protons and the protons getting converted to neutron (and releasing a positron in the exchange and the electron escaping out of orbit) so low?

Or is it the case that the energy released in the process is trivial relative to the ‘deuterium-tritium’ fusion?

Comment: It's not clear if you are suggesting using electron-nucleon fusion as an energy generation process, as people hope to with the fusion systems being developed for future use ?  If you're asking can we, with enough waste of energy, blast a bunch of electron towards nucleons and a small number will "fuse", then that's different.

Comment: `It's not clear if you are suggesting using electron-nucleon fusion as an energy generation process, as people hope to with the fusion systems being developed for future use`  ==> yes that's what I am trying to arrive at..  but when you say ..  " `If you're asking can we, with enough waste of energy, blast a bunch of electron towards nucleons and a small number will "fuse", then that's different. `" ====>an answer to that would help as well.. atleast with regard to understanding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrons are easily stripped from hydrogen molecules or atoms using strong electric fields. A tokamak is not necessary.

The reaction you cite is not fusion, as practiced in a tokamak. it consumes energy rather than releasing it.

Answer (score 3):

Electron capture $p+e^-\to n+\nu_e$ is endothermic (check the rest masses). It can only happen at sufficient $E_{CM}$ or when the proton is part of a suitable nucleus. You have the same problem (but more so) with positron decay $p\to n+e^++\nu_e$. We can't harness neutrino energy because their interaction with matter is too improbable.

Comment: @J.G. - What is Ecm that you refer to?

Comment: @RavindraHV See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414312/is-the-center-of-mass-energy-in-particle-physics-related-to-the-center-of-mass).

Comment: @fraxinus - yes, but that happens because it lowers the energy of the whole nucleus, not the one nucleon it changes.

Comment: @J.G. - Although you did mention that the reaction was endothermic, had not realized the implication.  Found [niels-nielsen's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/40292/niels-nielsen) answer to be more straightforward. Thank you for the details though !